# find all files with specific permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, find

I have been trying for hours to figure out the command syntax to find files that meet **any** of these criteria but I cannot seem to figure it out.

- user does not have read
- user does not have write
- group does not have read
- group does not have write
- other does not have read
- other has write
- other has execute

I started with this but this dosen't find all the expected files. For example it doesn't find files where other has read but also has execute.

```
find /path -type f \( ! -perm /u=rw,g=rw -or ! -perm /o=r \) -print
```

Comment: IMHO the problem is not  the syntax but the logic: `-perm /u=rw,g=rw` gets you all the files where any of these flags is set, so `! `-perm /u=rw,g=rw` get you the files where none of these flags is set. So maybe you want `! `-perm /u=rw,g=rw` (ie; not {all the flags set} which is the same as {at least one flag unset}.

Comment: Do you have a typo? Looks like you typed the same thing the last time...

Comment: Indeed. Meant `-perm -u=rw,g=rw`. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

```
 find ./ -type f ! \( -perm -u=rw -and -perm -g=rw -and -perm -o=r -and ! -perm /o=wx \)
```

## Long answer

As it seems easier to specify what we want (*x* **has** *y* permission) in `find`, let's try to conjugate the expression: we can see that a file that should **not** match has **all** of these conditions verified:

- user has read and write
- group has read and write
- other has read
- other does not have (write or execute)

So now we have more *has* than before (5 vs 2). I wrote the command that find the files that you do **not** want:

```
find ./ -type f -perm -u=rw -and -perm -g=rw -and -perm -o=r -and ! -perm /o=wx
```

To understand it you must mind the fact that `-` means *all of the permissions* and `/` means *any of the permissions*.

Then I conjugated it with ! and parenthesis to get the command at the top of this answer.

## Tests

Let's create files that verify only one of each of these criteria:

```
mkdir demo && cd demo
touch     a b c d e f g
chmod 777 a b c d e f g
chmod u-r a
chmod u-w   b
chmod g-r     c
chmod g-w       d
chmod o-r         e
chmod o-w a b c d e g
chmod o-x a b c d e f
```

Then let's create all the files that should not match:
We have freedoms on

- user execution rights
- group execution rights

Which gives exactly 2^2 = 4 types of full permissions that should not match.
Let's create 4 files with these criteria:

```
touch     h i j k
chmod 664 h i j k
chmod u+x h i
chmod g+x h   j
```

The provided command should match files a to e but not files h to k. Of course this test is not exhaustive because there are 256 types of permissions to test.